# PhpMyAdmin is suddenly showing errors

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I hope you're doing well.
Last week (friday) phpmyadmin was working just fine, but when I tried to work with it today it shows me some errors and doesn't show databases etc.
I'm workin with xampp on windows 7 (it's not my pc ...)

Here is the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
>   PhpMyAdmin\Core::arrayWrite() must be of the type array, null given,
>   called in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Config.php on line
>   1049 and defined in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Core.php:677
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Config.php(1049):
>   PhpMyAdmin\Core::arrayWrite('lang', NULL, 'fr') #1
>   C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Config.php(996):
>   PhpMyAdmin\Config->setUserValue(NULL, 'lang', 'fr', 'en') #2
>   C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\common.inc.php(453):
>   PhpMyAdmin\Config->loadUserPreferences() #3
>   C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php(27):
>   require_once('C:\xampp\phpMyA...') #4 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Core.php on line 677

Thank you for your interest.
Have a good day.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Please try clearing your browser cache and remove phpMyAdmin cookies, which start with "pma".

follow these steps

- Open up your phpMyAdmin in browser
- Press F12 to open Developer tools
- go to Application > Clear storage
- Clear all Cookies and Cache
- Try refreshing the page.

Comment: It works!! Thank you!! I thought I broke the pma, but I didn’t expect it was just a cookie problem.

Comment: this is definitely working at my side. well answered.

Answer (score 5):

Open up your phpMyAdmin url and press F12 for Developer mode .. go to Application Tab and Clear all Cookies .. refresh your phpMyAdmin page .. should be good to go .. enjoy

Comment: Please edit the question to explain why the instructions are expected to work. Do these instructions work in Firefox browser?

Answer (score 3):

follow these steps...

1. Open up your phpMyAdmin URL
2. Press F12 for Developer mode
3. go to Application Tab and
4. Clear all Cookies
5. refresh your phpMyAdmin page (if not working once restart the server and try again)

....  .. .. hurray!!! it's done  .. ... .....

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a "Application tab" in the Developers menu like mentioned by [Eliki Bula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60105495/2377961) and [Norbert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60795479/2377961)
But followed the steps to [clear a single site from the cache in Firefox](https://superuser.com/a/733154/585470) and "forgot" the url of `mypage/phpmadmin` and it worked, the error was gone.

So its fact.
The reason for this problem is somewhere in the Cookies from phpmyadmin, to you yust have to clear the cookies for this page on any way.

Answer (score 0):

Restore your database 'phpmyadmin' from your latest backup.
Before you stop MariaDb and then as usual, restore and start your DBMS again. It'll work.

Comment: How do I do that please?