# How to fix phpMyAdmin Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mb_strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php-8.1

PhpMyAdmin causes error while executing a query:

```
SELECT * FROM users u 
    INNER JOIN address a ON u.userid=a.id
    INNER JOIN  health_status h ON u.userid=h.uid
    WHERE u.userid='1634627411'
```

```
SELECT * 
from users u 
    INNER join friends f on u.userid=f.user 
    inner join friends f1 on u.userid = f1.friend 
WHERE f.user="1634627411"
```

Both the query throws error

the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mb_strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Display/Results.php:3095 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Display/Results.php(3095): mb_strtolower(NULL) #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Display/Results.php(2772): PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->getRowInfoForSpecialLinks(Array, Array) #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Display/Results.php(2613): PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->getRowValues(Object(mysqli_result), Array, 0, Array, Array, '', Array, 'SELECT * FROM u...', Array) #3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Display/Results.php(4219): PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->getTableBody(Object(mysqli_result), Array, Array, Array, false) #4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Sql.php(1364): PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->getTable(Object(mysqli_result), Array, Array, false) #5 /Application in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Display/Results.php on line 3095

I already tried this questions [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537958/phpmyadmin-is-suddenly-showing-errors/56538632).

My phpmyadmin version is also up to date 5.1.1

[image]

What's the error mean and how to solve it?

Comment: Does this happen when you run other queries or just this one

Comment: *PhpMyAdmin causes error while executing a query* The error is not related to shown query. SQL code is absolutely legal. The only point - what is the reason for to use string literal instead of numeric one in WHERE?

Comment: When I run `select * from users` it works but no when I use `inner join` syntax

Comment: I think what @Akina means is what happens if you try `WHERE u.userid=1634627411` i.e. without the quotes around the numeric value

Comment: You added another query, but you dont say if it worked or also causes the error

Comment: @Akina because the `userid` is `varchar(20)`

Comment: @RiggsFolly updated and both query results in error and I have answered for akina's question please help me with this

Comment: Are you sure you're using 5.1.1? The line numbers are not matching what's seen here https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/libraries/classes/Display/Results.php

Comment: @aynber Proof screenshot added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade your phpMyAdmin version. Version 5.1.1 is not compatible with PHP 8.1.

As of posting, the new version doesn't seem ready yet, so for the time being downgrade to PHP 8.0.

Comment: I'm using XAMPP server to execute php code and now the current version of my php is 7.4.24 how to upgrade this to 8.0

Comment: This error does not exist in PHP 8.0. So you can use PHP 8.0 without major issues. I stopped using XAMPP long time ago so I can't remember what is their upgrade process.